# Mapstruck null failure for inner field mapped by another mapper

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct

In my application, each chat contains a list of messages, and each message contains info about the users who are their sender and receiver. However, I’m struggling to use a mapper with mapstruct that from a chat mapper would allow me to map both the list of messages and the user info related to each message, which are mapped by the message mapper.

So this fails with valid message, but null userTo and userFrom id.

```
return chatRepository.findAll()
        .stream()
        .map(chatMapper::toModel)
        .toList();
```

But when it's replaced by the below piece where I map each message and then manually add them to a chat, it passes:

```
List<ChatEntity> chatEntityList = chatRepository.findAll();

List<Chat> chatList = new ArrayList<>();
for (ChatEntity chatEntity : chatEntityList) {
    List<Message> messageList = chatEntity.getMessageEntityList()
            .stream()
            .map(messageMapper::toModel)
            .toList();

    Chat chat = Chat.builder()
            .id(chatEntity.getId())
            .messageList(messageList)
            .build();

    chatList.add(chat);
}
return chatList;
```

I’ve been trying for days, but am really at loss at why this is?

These are my mappers:

```
@Mapper //tried @Mapper(uses = MessageMapper.class) but the result is the same
public interface ChatMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "messageList", target = "messageEntityList")
    ChatEntity toEntity(Chat chat);

    @Mapping(source = "messageEntityList", target = "messageList")
    Chat toModel(ChatEntity chatEntity);
}

@Mapper
public interface MessageMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "userFromId", target = "userFromEntity.id")
    @Mapping(source = "userToId", target = "userToEntity.id")
    MessageEntity toEntity(Message message);

    @Mapping(source = "userFromEntity.id", target = "userFromId")
    @Mapping(source = "userToEntity.id", target = "userToId")
    Message toModel(MessageEntity messageEntity);
}
```

And here models:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Chat {

    private UUID id;

    @JsonProperty("messages")
    private List<Message> messageList;
}

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Message {

    private UUID id;
    private String content;
    private ZonedDateTime creationDate;
    private UUID parentId;
    private UUID userFromId;
    private UUID userToId;
}
```

And entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChatEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chatEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MessageEntity> messageEntityList;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MessageEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private ZonedDateTime creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_to_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity userToEntity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_from_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity userFromEntity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ChatEntity chatEntity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am aware you mentioned that you obtained the same results but in my opinion using the following `Mapper` definition should give you the right results:

```java
@Mapper(uses = MessageMapper.class)
public interface ChatMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "messageList", target = "messageEntityList")
    ChatEntity toEntity(Chat chat);

    @Mapping(source = "messageEntityList", target = "messageList")
    Chat toModel(ChatEntity chatEntity);
}
```

If this code doesn't work, please, pay attention to your JPA relationships: all are defined as lazy, and perhaps they haven'e been initialized when the mapper is evaluated.

Please, analyze the source code of the generated mappers, it will give you a good understanding about the actual code that it being executed.

As a work around, consider include the identifiers of the user that sended and received the message as additional read-only columns in your `MessageEntity`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MessageEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private ZonedDateTime creationDate;

    @Column(name = "user_to_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private UUID userToEntityId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_to_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity userToEntity;

    @Column(name = "user_from_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private UUID userFromEntityId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_from_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity userFromEntity;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ChatEntity chatEntity;
```

and modify `MessageMapper` to take into account the new columns:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MessageMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "userFromId", target = "userFromEntityId")
    @Mapping(source = "userToId", target = "userToEntityId")
    MessageEntity toEntity(Message message);

    @Mapping(source = "userFromEntityId", target = "userFromId")
    @Mapping(source = "userToEntityId", target = "userToId")
    Message toModel(MessageEntity messageEntity);
}
```

Please, if you adopt this new approach, pay attention to the way the relationships are resolved.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer made me revisit the `uses = MessageMapper.class` option and it worked now once I verified it directly in the application. Before, the failure was happening in the tests, which led me believe my application code was also wrong. The unit tests themselves were the one causing the issue, however, as I among some other things, I was missing @InjectMocks to be in conjunction with @Spy for my ChatMapper.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @FrancislainyCampos. I am very happy to hear that you were able to solve the problem.